# PowerShell Winforms Timer scoping issue with variables

Tags: winforms, powershell

I"m working on a simple winforms app in powershell to do the following:

- Display 4 separate computer names with buttons
- The buttons should start a timer for the computer name
- When the timer ends, it should tell the computer name to fire off a remote command
- The basic idea is that they can fill out a timer in minutes for each machine, press the start button, and once that time is up it will fire the command off to the machine.

I mocked it up in winforms and ran into an issue with the timer:

- I use a button to call a function with a parameter
- that function then starts the timer and adds a timer tick event
- the tick event tries to use the parameter from the function, but its null

Here is a simple code example of the scoping issue:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

$Form = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.Text = "Form"
$Form.BackColor = "#6c6b6b"
$Form.TopMost = $true
$Form.Width = 800
$Form.Height = 600

$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer
$timer.Interval = 5000

function fun1
{
    param($computername)
    write-host "Computername: $computername in fun1" -ForegroundColor Green
    $timerSB = {
        write-host "Computername: $computername in timerSB" -ForegroundColor cyan
        fun2 -ComputerName $computername
    }
    $script:timer.add_tick($timerSB)
    $script:timer.Start()
}

function fun2
{
    param($computername)
    write-host "Computername: $computername in fun2" -ForegroundColor yellow

}

fun1 -computername localhost

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
$timer.Dispose()
$Form.Dispose()
```

**Questions:**

1. Any idea how to get around this scoping issue to keep passing those values along? I"m sure I'm overlooking a simple way to do this, but I can't seem to get it to work as planned.
2. Are there any issues I'm overlooking with the WinForm timer control if I try to run 4 different timers? If so, is there another timer control I should be using that can help me accomplish this?

Comment: Could you please kindly state which version of PowerShell that you are using? Doubtlessly, there is a lot of examples on the Microsoft PowerShell online docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-hk/powershell/scripting/basic-cookbooks?view=powershell-6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two issues with your script:

- You have a single (global) timer with will be overwritten each time you restart it. Meaning that you probably want to put the `$timer = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Timer` inside the `Fun1` function
  *Note:* that you might get some leakage every time you relaunch the timer, if you care about that, you might have to build something like a self destruct
- Your `$timerSB` command is evaluated at the moment the timer ends but meanwhile the `$ComputerName` might have been changed. For this, you might have to build create a `ScriptBlock` that evaluates the `$ComputerName` at the moment the timer is started:

```
$timerSB = [ScriptBlock]::Create("
    write-host ""Computername: $computername in timerSB"" -ForegroundColor cyan
    fun2 -ComputerName $computername
")
```

Comment: Thank you! I was trying to figure out how to pull out the local value of $computername when generating  the scriptblock and I didn't even think to just call the scriptblock type.

The gloabl timer was just to make sure anyone copying/pasting my sample didn't run into dispose issues.